# Legend in an image generated by OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, legend

I'm plotting an image with the following code:

```
cv2.imshow('',I)
cv2.circle(I,tuple(xy),radius=1,c=(255,0,0),thickness=1)
cv2.circle(I,tuple(uv),radius=1,c=(0,0,255),thickness=1)
```

Is it possible to add a legend to the image? I guess cv2.putText is an option but it seems to me a cumbersome one.

Thanks for any help!

cv2 version = 4.1.2,
python version = 3.7.5

Comment: Yes, you can use cv2.putText in image.